# TextView text multiple lines for Android v4.1+

Tags: android, textview, multiline, word-wrap

I have a TextView in Android with a Text that can vary quite a bit in length. It could be a single word, it could also be more than ten full sentences.

My TextView has `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`. I've looked around and found a lot of ways to make it wrap over multiple lines (some requiring multiple of these):

- `android:scrollHorizontally="false"`
- `android:singleLine="false"`
- `android:ellipsize="none"`
- `android:maxLines="10"`
- etc.

So my question is: Which should I use to wrap my TextView-Text in Android version 4.1+?

PS: I haven't tested any of these yet, but since I've found so many different answers on SO-questions about Text-Wrapping, I was wondering what the "best" method is (for my Android version).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using:

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ...
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="10" />
```

When I looked at the `singleLine` in Eclipse it gave the following java-doc:

> Constrains the text to a single horizontally scrolling line instead of
>   letting it wrap onto multiple lines, and advances focus instead of 
>   inserting a newline when you press the enter key. * Deprecated:   This
>   attribute is deprecated. Use "maxLines" instead to change the   layout
>   of a static text, and use the "textMultiLine" flag in the   inputType
>   attribute instead for editable text views (if both   singleLine and
>   inputType are supplied, the inputType flags will   override the value
>   of singleLine). [boolean]

So I now use `maxLines="10"`, since I don't want an entire life-story to be inside the TextView, 10 lines should be a good maximum. I've added the `ellipsize="end"` to have three dots (`...`) at the end of the text when it has more than 10 lines. And the `scrollHorizontally="false"` does the trick of allowing multiple lines without a horizontal scroll-bar.

Answer (score 0):

```
    try setting this attributes:
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:singleLine="false"

here
to elipsize, a neologism, means to shorten text using an ellipsis, i.e. three dots ... or more commonly ligature …, to stand in for the omitted bits.

Say original value pf text view is aaabbbccc and its fitting inside the view

start's output will be : ...bccc

end's output will be : aaab...

middle's output will be : aa...cc

marquee's out put will be : aaabbbccc auto sliding from right to left
```

Comment: You answer is in the low quality post queue. Please add an explanation to your answer to prevent deletion.

Comment: Hmm, I stated I use Android v4.1+ and `fill_parent` renamed to `match_parent` from Android API 8+ so is 'deprecated' (though the effect stays the same behind the scenes). Also, I just found out that `singleLine` is deprecated as well according to the java-doc that shows up in Eclipse, so I ended up using `scrollHorizontally` with `maxLines="10"`.